# Can anyone identify this biplane in 1940s Orange, MA?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

The picture was taken at Orange Municipal Airport in Orange, MA, in the 1940's.  I can't identify the logo either.  [image]

Comment: I know it isn't, by my first impression of the logo on the vertical stabilizer was that of the [Indianapolis Motor Speedway](https://imsdotcom.azureedge.net/-/media/IMS/logos/indianapolis-motor-speedway.png?vs=1&d=20201027T160008Z).

Answer (score 14):

It may be an [Alliance A-1 Argo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance_A-1_Argo), a sturdy two-seat open-cockpit biplane. Vertical stabilizer shape and structure, the 5 stiffeners or ridges on the upper wing, large diameter radial engine, wing cutout and knob on the vertical stabilizer, and vents behind the engine are quite distinctive. Logo on the vertical stabilizer seems to match too.

No clue about the logo, whether it is aircraft manufacturer's logo or some operator or company logo (there may be something Danish about the one I found because one can read "pr... Luftfartøj" behind smiling pilot's elbow, and OY-DID is in the OY-AAA to OY-ZZZ range alloted to Denmark).

[image: alliance argo]
([source](http://airwar.ru/enc/law1/a1.html))

Comment: Wing cutout and knob on the vertical stabilizer match as well. Good find.

Comment: @quietflyer are those ridges the 5 longitudinal things I named stiffeners? (not actually knowing what they are named nor their actual purpose?)

Comment: @quietflyer not sure about this, but I think the middle part is a tank made of a thin metal sheet that has to be stiffened with those 5 folds

Comment: That it for sure.  Nice job!

Comment: nice input and edit about writings and immatriculation being danish and not german @CamilleGoudeseune

Answer (score 3):

The emblem on the tail is a logo for the Argo airplane, however I can't find a good high resolution copy as they didn't use it in their advertising at all, and a different logo was used on their Blue Bird.
It is a pair of wings with ARGO written in an arc over it, and while the Blue Bird logo has a star in the middle, this doesn't - but it could be a ship, as the most common device associated with Argo is a Phoenician ship.
Their advertising really plots the decline of the company - full page ads with pictures while Alliance, small text-only ads while Hess, and nothing while Warrior.
Alliance's logo was a very simple overlapped double A.